# Matplotlib limit row's plotted from CSV

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently logging temperature and humidity levels from a sensor to a CSV file in the current format:-

```
2016-04-05 20:21:39,15.50,49.30
2016-04-05 20:22:40,15.50,49.30
2016-04-05 20:23:40,15.40,49.30
2016-04-05 20:24:41,15.40,49.40
```

I am then using `numpy.loadtxt` to read in the values to plot:-

```
dates, temp = np.loadtxt('templog.csv',
                         converters={0: datefunc},
                         unpack=True,
                         delimiter=',',
                         usecols=(0, 1))

dates2, humid = np.loadtxt('templog.csv',
                           converters={0: datefunc},
                           unpack=True,
                           delimiter=',',
                           usecols=(0, 2))
```

This all works absolutely fine but it's plotting every metric since the beginning of time. I would like to limit the 'x' last number of rows to be plotted to allow me do just the last 24 hours for example.

Is this possible using a CSV file as the source or would I be better off inserting the data in to a sqlite3 database and then using appropriate select queries to pull the data I want and plot.

Comment: Can you show us your plot and tell us what you want to change?

Comment: Not sure showing you the plot will help at all. I just don't want to plot every line in the CSV file. If it's 500, 1000 or 10,000 lines long, how do I plot only the last 100 lines of the file?

Comment: Just slice the part of the arrays you want to plot. Look up slicing syntax and how it works with Numpy arrays.  And maybe load the three arrays in one call to `loadtxt()`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

With inspiration from @blackJack, I was able to use array slicing inside the plot_date to plot the last x items in the arrays produced by the numpy unpack e.g `temp[-10:]` -

```
hours = 24 # How many hours to show on the graph
logtime = 5 # How many minutes each sample is taken

ax.plot_date(dates[-((hours*60)/logtime):],
             temp[-((hours*60)/logtime):], ls='-', marker='', color='red')
ax2.plot_date(dates[-((hours*60)/logtime):],
              humid[-((hours*60)/logtime):], ls='-', marker='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your data read as it is. Just limit the plotting as you like.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dates, temp)
ax.set_xlim(['yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:dd', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:DD'])
```

Comment: Attempted this method could not get it to work in my scenario. Posting something I was able to get work.